# mod_rewrite - RewriteCond - why is the comparison syntax necessary?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have here three conditions but I can't find the real difference because they do the same work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

This site (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) says:

> Syntax: `RewriteCond TestString CondPattern [flags]`

CondPattern is usually a perl compatible regular expression, but there is additional syntax available to perform other useful tests against the Teststring:

Why do I need an additional comparison syntax if the condition itself has the task to compare against the regex?

Answer (score 2):

They do not do the same work.

Straight `RewriteCond` assumes that the condition expression is a regular expression.

The syntax with `=` and `!=` performs a simple string comparison.

The **results** are the same in your example **only because the string you used has no regexp syntax**.

Confusion about this can lead to bug and security issues.

For example, an attacker can exploit a condition like the one below by just sending a "Host" header with `wwwXexample.com`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.com [NC]
```

Whereas the condition below will match **only** if the host is `www.example.com`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.example.com [NC]
```

There are other implications, most notably performance: straight string comparison is way faster than regexp matching.

Rule of thumb: use regexp if you want to match against a pattern. Otherwise use exact string comparison.